# Colon if statement difference

Tags: c++, syntax, expression

How are these two lines of statement different ?

```
a<=20? b=30: c= 30;
(a<=20)?b:c = 30;
```

If i give a value of a = 20 then

First line gives b = 20 , c =0
Second line gives b = 0 , c  = 0

Not an assignment question.

Comment: It is an *assignment* question; you don't *assign* a value to `b` ;)

Comment: This works well. initialize b

Answer (score 1):

According to the rule of [ternary conditional operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator),

`a<=20? b=30: c= 30;` is same as:

```
if (a <= 20) {
    b = 30;
} else {
    c = 30;
}
```

and `(a<=20)?b:c = 30;` is same as:

```
if (a <= 20) {
    b;
} else {
    c = 30; 
}
```

So the difference between case#1 and case#2 is whether `b` get setted when the condition is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

operator precedence:
this:

```
(a<=20)?b:c = 30;
```

is interpreted as:

```
(a<=20) ? (b) : (c=30) ;
```

you probably want

```
((a<=20)?b:c) = 30;
```